# Set the innerText into the <p> element

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm experimentig with ASP.NET WebForms and I'm trying to change `innerText` of the `<p>` element. Let I've an `test.aspx` test page which contains the following:

```
<p id="pageName" runat="server">Title</p>
```

and code-behind test.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    pageName.InnerHtml = "This is the changed text";
}
```

But when I'm running this page in browser the `<p>` tag contained `Title` yet. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `pageName.InnerText` instead.
make sure you update the text in initial load of the page or during post back, otherwise it won't work.

And add `contenteditable` attribute:

```
<p id="pageName" contenteditable="true" runat="server">Title</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it works for me even without contenteditable="true" attribute.

Comment: @Nanosoft I know it. The time to accept is not expired.